# Requiring unknown module "499" error in React Native

Tags: android, linux, reactjs, react-native

[image]

I am getting this error. I have tried running npm install multiple times but this is still there, how to get this worked?

Comment: try command "rm -rf /node_modules && npm install" then run "react-native start"

Comment: Sometimes it also helps to just close your command line terminal, before restarting the app

Comment: @soroushchehresa this worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, remove all the installed npm packages and install them again by running the following command:

```
$ rm -rf /node_modules && npm i
```

And then, start React-Native again by the following command:

```
$ react-native start
```

Answer (score 6):

Most times you may not need to delete your node modules and reinstall as some answers may suggest, if you have installed your packages previously without errors. Most times all you need to do is to close or terminate metro bundler and restart. Or just run `react-native run-ios (or android)` after terminating the metro bundler.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I realized another app was running.
I stopped Metro Bundler then run `react-native run-ios`, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This can crop up if Metro Bundler is already running. You don't necessarily need to nuke your `node_modules`.

Often this can be fixed (on Mac) with:

- Find process listening on 8081: `sudo lsof -i :8081`

> **8081** is the port Metro bundler runs on by default.
> [image: list of processes for port 8081]

- Kill process: `kill -9 [pid]`

> for the example in the image this would be `kill - 9 20292`

- Run app again via xcode, react-native cli, etc.

Ref: [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/troubleshooting#port-already-in-us)

Comment: It's work for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by soroush in the comment, I run

```
rm -rf /node_modules && npm install
react-native run-android
```

It worked, but actually the problem was with firebase@5.0.4 , I installed firebase 5.0.3 and everything was normal.

```
npm install firebase
```